# Запятая перед словом даже

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста ставится ли запятая перед словом "даже" в данном предложении? Уже не стучат дятлы, не пищат волчата даже барсучата спрятались. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. Это бессоюзное сложное предложение с тремя основами. *Даже* - не союз, а частица, употребляемая для выделения и усиления слова, к которому относится. Но если было бы *и даже* (союз + частица), запятая всё равно ставилась бы, т. к. союз *и* соединял бы простые предложения в составе сложного.

Comment: Да, согласна с Софией. На стыке частей предложения "даже" - союз.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед ДАЖЕ ставится, но здесь частица ДАЖЕ является присоединительным союзом , имеющим значение добавления, уточнения с оттенком усиления:Читал много, д. испортил себе зрение. Ветер сильный, д. верхушки деревьев клонит. Запятая перед присоединительными союзами ставится в обязательном порядке.

В качестве присоединительных союзов могут выступать:

а) собственно присоединительные союзы  ДА И,  ПРИЧЁМ,  ПРИТОМ,  ТОЖЕ,  ТАКЖЕ;

б) другие союзы в значении присоединительных:  ДА,  И,  ИЛИ,  НО;

в) вводные слова и частицы:  ДАЖЕ,  ОСОБЕННО,  ГЛАВНЫМ ОБРАЗОМ, НАПРИМЕР.